# Is there any way to force market to update and install apps one at a time?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I'm having problems with my Samsung galaxy Captivate where whenever I attempt to update all the apps in market, every single app begins downloading and installing all at the same time and the result is always the same, it crashes (20+ simultaneous downloads and installs would definably overrun any system!).

Is there any way to set it such that android is only allowed to download and install a single app at a time? I want to be able to run the batch updates but I want them to be queued up as opposed to all running at once and overwhelming my system.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com) it does downloads sequentially. Unfortunately you'll still need to click "Okay" for each to start the download but it'll save you a few taps.

Comment: Well i know you can individually install them on appbrain, but it is far from automated. I'd like the "update all" button, just not the "update all at once" effect.